# How can I force a tikz image to go to the bottom of the page?

Tags: latex

I'm using this code to implement a "background image" on my page:

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics{Images/picture.pdf}};
```

However, I'd like it to show up at the bottom of the page. I've tried changing the `current page.center` and played around with `\vfill` but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67976/how-can-i-position-a-picture-precisely-on-a-page) may be what you are looking for (adapted for this question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[anchor=south west, %anchor is bottom left corner of the graphic
      xshift=5cm, %shifting around
      yshift=-5cm] 
     at (current page.south west) %left bottom corner of the page
     {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{tiger}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```